# Same Validation MSE again, and again

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, regression, linear-regression

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
scaler_X, scaler_Y = MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler()
scaler_X.fit(X)
scaler_Y.fit(Y)
X_scale, Y_scale = scaler_X.transform(X),scaler_Y.transform(Y)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_scale,Y_scale, test_size=.2, random_state=42)
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_Validation = train_test_split(X_train,Y_train, test_size=.4, random_state=42)
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model1, epochs=50, verbose=1)
def base_model1():
    input_dim = X.shape[1]
    output_dim = 1
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4181, input_dim= input_dim,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation= 'sigmoid')) ## 19 Fib
    model.add(Dense(2584, input_dim= 4181,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation= 'sigmoid'))      ## 18 Fib
    model.add(Dense(1597, input_dim= 2584 ,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation= 'sigmoid'))     ## 17 Fib
    model.add(Dense(987, input_dim= 1597,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation = 'relu'))       ## 16 Fib
    model.add(Dense(610, input_dim= 987,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation = 'relu'))        ## 15 Fib 
    #now output
    model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='relu'))
    # Compile model with appropirate loss, optimizer - variant of gradient descent and metrics to keep tab on progress
    #sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['MeanSquaredError',
        'AUC',])
    return model
h5filename = str(input("Name of the H5 file named: "))
trained = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_data=(X_validation,Y_Validation),validation_batch_size=None)
trained.model.save(h5filename)
y_hat = trained.model.predict(X_test)
pd.DataFrame(trained.history).plot(figsize=(5,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting the same Validation error in the following code, and it comes out to be straight lines. I set up my Neural Network to do regression, and it keeps giving me the same value, and a horizontal line as the line. I am bit confused could there advice to the right direction to get a better regression?

Comment: Could you explain why the upper three `Dense` layers have `sigmoid` activation whereas the other layers have `relu` activation?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I am new to this, in fact, I am learning this right now in my first Machine Learning Course. I am just trying functions, my professor is using in his lectures, its really trial, and error any advice is helpful or resource maybe I can change the question to resources for ML activation and Linear Regression.

Comment: Why are you using the `relu` activation function in your output layer? If you are modelling a regression problem you don't normally have an activation function on the output layer. Relu would be particularly problematic if your target includes negative numbers as it won't produce negative outputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "it comes out to be straight lines" and "horizontal line as the line"? Do you mean the validation loss is not changing across the training epochs?